# Google Sheet Formula: How to calculate and print out an array result?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

For example, if I put following values into A1-A3

```
A1: 3000  // Initial value
A2：0.99  // Decrease percentage
A3: 5     // Decrease times
```

What formula should I put in B1 so I can have the following result in B1-B5?

```
B1: 3000
B2: 2970   //3000*0.99
B3: 2940.3 //3000*0.99*0.99
B4: 2910.897 // 3000*0.99*0.99*0.99
B5: 2881.78803 //3000*0.99*0.99*0.99*0.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=arrayformula($A$1*($A$2^(row(offset(B1,,,$A$3))-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(A1*A2^SEQUENCE(A3; 1; ))
```

[image]